# Swift: Uploading image to Firebase cloud storage when user closes app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

How do I upload an image to Firebase Storage when the user terminates the app?

Here's my code:

```
firebaseRef.child("\(uid)/\(filePath)").put(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
   // NOTE: This spot never reaches when user closes the app
   if error != nil || metadata == nil {
      log.error("Fail to store image in cloud storage")
   } else {
      // Do something with the metadata url
   }
```

As you can see, the async completion block never completes if the user terminates the app and I'm not able to upload the user's image to Firebase Storage

How do I safeguard against user terminating the app after uploading the picture? I have a preliminary idea. Could I store the image in `CoreData`/`NSUserDefaults` temporarily, and retry the upload when the user opens the app again?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. At present, on iOS, there's no way of persisting and restarting the upload or download if the app is backgrounded or killed. This feature [exists on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes) (since the Activity is reset on screen rotation, making this a far more common issue), and we're planning on making it available on iOS in the future.

Eventually, we want to simply make this a flag `[FIRStorage enablePersistentUploads:YES]` or similar, to automatically do this for you, so you don't have to think about it at all.

Comment: assuming no progress has been made since this is almost a year old now

Comment: Two and a half years since this answer now - I can't see any way of doing this through the SDK yet?

Comment: And another two years and still not implemented :)

Comment: I don't work on this anymore, but pull requests are always welcome :) https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseStorage/Sources/FIRStorage.m#L343-L369

Comment: @MikeMcDonald! Funny seeing you here haha.  Any chance there's a way to use URLSession to manage an upload to cloud storage?  I need to write a Capacitor plugin to do background uploads with Firebase, and iOS is the straggler here.

Comment: @J.Sheets you can; I used `GTMSessionFetcher` to do resumable uploads, but you can use NSURLSession if you'd like, just set the URL params properly: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseStorage/Sources/FIRStorageUploadTask.m#L96-L116. You can do non-resumable uploads via https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert and replacing the URL and auth credentials, I believe.