# Firebase storage background upload using URLSession?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsurlsession, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase in a iMessage extension and I need to upload data even if the user kills the app. The only way to do this is by using [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1). Is there a way to upload to Firebase storage using URLSession or is there another way to upload data without killing the app.

The following does not work:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
```

Since iMessage extensions does not have access to UIApplication.shared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Uploading image to Firebase cloud storage when user closes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255849/swift-uploading-image-to-firebase-cloud-storage-when-user-closes-app)