# swift - Upload image to firebase storage when the user closes app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I upload an image to Firebase Storage, if the user closes the app while the operation is taking place?

Right now, if I leave the app in background, it seems to complete the operation successfully, but whenever I close it while uploading, the results are inconsistent.

I found the answer in an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255849/swift-uploading-image-to-firebase-cloud-storage-when-user-closes-app), but since it is almost 4 years old, wanted to know if there is a way to do it now.